# Download problem of ubuntu desktop

Tags: installation, wubi, downloads

I was downloading ubuntu desktop and the downloader got stuck on amd64.tar.xz file . I closed the installation and the restarted it , it uninstalled the previous one but then again the downloader is stuck on the same file . OS is Win7 Home Premium.

How do I come out of this situation ?

Comment: are you trying wubi install?

Comment: Do you have a 32-bit processor? In that case, installing the 64-bit version of Ubuntu will give errors.

Comment: @Web-E Yes am going to wubi install

Comment: I have a 64 bit processor and 64bit OS

Comment: Have you checked you Internet connection?

Comment: do not download during wubi installation. If you wish then download updated iso directly. Unplug your network device during wubit installation. If it will not help then pls provide your processor and ram information

Answer (score 0):

Since it is stuck in downloaing there might be some problem with internet connection.

I will suggest,

1. Download appropriate ISO from http://releases.ubuntu.com/precise/
2. Copy the ISO to same directory of wubi.exe
3. Now run wubi.exe

If you are using 32bit version of ubuntu. Use `--32bit` argument.
Open `cmd`. Navigate to the directory and then execute `wubi.exe --32bit`